# Python : Understanding logical or of two object in parameter

Tags: python, logical-operators

In [this python code line 256 to 266](https://github.com/ph4r05/ph4-runner/blob/cac80d6bc62cd5bdf5424ef54a24ea6f2279bafc/ph4runner/__init__.py)

this use  [run in sarge](https://sarge.readthedocs.io/en/0.1.6/reference.html#functions)

```
        p = run(
            cmd,
            input=self.feeder,
            async_=True,
            stdout=self.stdout or Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1),
            stderr=self.stderr or Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1),
            cwd=self.cwd,
            env=self.env,
            shell=self.shell,
            **run_args
        )
```

I trouble with understand OR logical operator  `stdout=self.stdout or Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1)`

this `OR` two object in parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my understanding, `OR` is used when you want to specify a default value for parameter (second statement) if first statement is not available (None).

In your case, if `self.stdout=None`, `stdout` will have value of second statement (`Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1)`).

Answer (score 0):

If `stdout=self.stdout` is **true** and `Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1)` is **true**, then the entire statement is **true**.

If `stdout=self.stdout` is **true** and `Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1)` is **false**, then the entire statement is **true**, and vice versa.

If `stdout=self.stdout` is **false** and `Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1)` is **false**, then the entire statement is **false**.

Comment: Hi, I think is not true, because this argument accept object (stream) not boolean

Answer (score 0):

It will use the first "truthy" variable. In your example if self.stdout is null, it will then assign to Capture(timeout=0.1, buffer_size=1).
Here's a great resource https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/
Look to the section regarding "Non-Boolean Contexts"

Comment: Hi I read Your link in realpython But really have not see any "reference" or example show can use "or" to return one  function from two  other question what happen if both is not null !